# Is it possible to plug 50 webcam on a computer for a 3d scanner?

Tags: usb, webcam

I want to make a 3D scanner, at first I used a Lumix TZ20 and got good result, then a Coolpix L27 (50€) and got the same result.
Then my phone's camera, which were good too.

Now I'd like to try webcams.

But can you plug 50 webcam on a computer and use them?
I mean, I can write a java program to control them but will it be possible to get them to take a picture exactly at the same time?

Transfert would obviously take some time but is there some kind of buffer in the camera which will store the picture until it is transfered to the computer?

Thanks.

My hardware configuration since some have asked :

```
Core i5 3570K 3.40 GHz (Ivy Bridge)
Motherboard Gigabyte Z77-D3H
16GB of DDR3
AMD Radeon R9 290X
Alimentation corsair RM750
```

Comment: The hard part will certainly be the software to analyse the data, not the hardware.  Also, 50 seems like overkill.

Comment: Please provide your hardware specs and power supply wattage and etc.

Comment: Your specs are good your mobo has 4 usb 3.0 ports somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

**It is possible to get it to work, but much pre-planning is needed.**

Your biggest problem is POWER.  USB supports 127 devices per hub in theory.
First you need enough USB ports and bandwidth and hubs.

You need several USB 3.0 **powered hub** (this is critical) and have lots of power.
You will need 50+ usb plugs in a combination of **powered** hubs.

Each one is going to take the full 500ma * 50 = **25 amps@5 volts** total.
**You need to spread that kind of load of many USB hubs.**

> Now 25 amps might seem impossible crazy but 1 amp @120v is about 20 amps at 5 volts.
>
> If you don't have USB 3.0 the bandwidth is going to be so horrible don't even start.

The USB 3.0 hub can have 2.0 ports but the total bandwidth from all of them will require 3.0 worth of bandwidth.

You will need at least 2 usb 3.0 port if not 4 to meet the bandwidth requirements.
If you have 4 you will need, on average, 13 webcams per port. (13*0.5= 6.5 amps@5V)

Caution the 28 port has only 4 3.0 ports, but each port has 500ma and depending on the hub chip inside it might still work.

[Orico 10port](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1GK11A2530&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-_-pla-_-E-Book%20Accessories-_-9SIA1GK11A2530&ef_id=UrY79gAABdCvKGCz:20140112054653:s)
[28 port](http://www.cyberguys.com/product-details/?productid=63202&rH=1706)
[12 port](http://www.espow.com/product_info.php?products_id=4971&currency=USD&gsc=googleshopping&gclid=CNn17vj297sCFbBAMgodJl4Aiw)

Comment: Note the limit on devices is not per port but per host controller which might have more than one port.

Comment: Do you guys really thinks USB3 is going to change something? I'm just taking a picture, thus getting 50 images wich is about 2 seconds of video with a single camera.

Comment: Unless each of the camera has local storage it will change things a lot.  USB 2= 480mbps USB 3 =5000mbps.

Comment: Get your project off on the right foot with one of these.  **http://www.ebay.com/itm/like/191002640729?lpid=82** Then 6 qty 10 port hubs and your set.

Comment: Just bought 3 webcams, I'm going to take a picture of a chronometers to see how much delay there is betwen each pic

Comment: Although starting small is good 3 is in no way comparable to 50.